# Como traduzir o termo pejorativo "nice guy" do inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês

O *[nice guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_guy)*, no sentido pejorativo, é o cara que age como amigo da mulher com a intenção oculta de progredir para um relacionamento sexual. Como traduzir para o português?

*Editado*: acho que minha definição acima não deixou clara a conotação do termo. Vou elaborar.

Na cultura dos Estados Unidos, da Inglaterra, etc., e especialmente na [comunidade de sedução](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickup_artist) e na [comunidade *Red Pill*](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheRedPill/), cujas filosofias são bem explicadas pelos livros [*The Game*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0060554738), de Neil Strauss, e [*The Rational Male*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1492777862), de Rollo Tomassi, acredita-se no aforismo *Nice guys finish last*. De acordo com o aforismo, mulheres se sentem mais atraídas pelos *bad boys*, os cafajestes, mesmo que estes não as tratem tão bem e tendam a, por exemplo, abandoná-las após a primeira relação sexual. [Este vídeo](https://youtu.be/xfeys7Jfnx8) de música ilustra a ideia.

O *nice guy* disfarça seu interesse sexual de interesse amistoso não por ser (conscientemente) maquiavélico, mas por ser carente. [Neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkpgdYZ_bDg) de um membro da comunidade de sedução, os *nice guys* são descritos como *boring, puritanical, judgmental, inclined to qualifying themselves, mommy's boys, white knights, people-pleasers, needy because of their scarcity, pedestalizing of women, under the thumb, providers, bland, vanilla* e *prone to hiding their intentions with girls*.

Comment: Eu diria que não há uma tradução e que o termo tem que ser substituído por uma descrição. Até onde sei o conceito não é cristalizado no português (brasileiro) ainda. O que talvez mais se aproxime é `falso`, mas a palavra tem um significado muito mais amplo que o desejado.

Comment: Detached, considerou a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/6065/2764) do Pedro? Me parece a melhor sugestão em todo esse tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma totalmente **informal**, ultimamente na internet é muito utilizado a palavra `gado`.

> **Gado:** conjunto de animais (carneiros, cavalos, bois, cabritos etc.) criados para diversos fins.

Mas podemos ignorar esse significado pois nesse caso é usado como forma de **ironia**, para pessoas que fazem de tudo para outra pessoa com o propósito de ter algum **ganho** (normalmente sentimental).

Outra alternativa seria `pau-mandado`.

> **Pau-mandado:** pessoa que obedece a tudo incondicionalmente, sem objeções, resistência ou protesto.

Entretanto esse é mais utilizado em **relacionamentos**, onde o parceiro faz tudo que o cônjuge pede.

Comment: O *nice guy* é submisso à mulher a fim de agradá-la, assim como o gado ou pau-mandado. Sua resposta captura bem essa conotação da palavra.

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade que traduz a hipocrisia da situação, mantendo a ironia da palavra e aplicando-se exclusivamente a homens, é [bom-moço](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=d8qY).

Comment: Ótima sugestão. "`Iron` Indivíduo hipócrita que se faz passar por pessoa séria e honesta." se aplica muito bem mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

**O título da pergunta**: O nice guy, no sentido pejorativo, é o cara que age como amigo da mulher com a intenção oculta de progredir para um relacionamento sexual. Como traduzir para o português?

Uma vez que o corpo da pergunta foi editado, esclareço que minhas definições de nice guy, de caráter pejorativo ou não, são as mesmas que encontro nos dicionários. O trecho a seguir, extraído da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_guy), explica bem os dois significados, positivo e negativo, da expressão.

> - A nice guy is an informal term for an (often young) adult male who portrays himself with characteristics such as being gentle, compassionate, sensitive and vulnerable.  **The term is used both positively and negatively**. **When used positively**, and particularly when used as a preference or description by someone else, it is intended to imply a male who puts the needs of others before his own, avoids confrontations, does favors, gives emotional support, tries to stay out of trouble, and generally acts nicely towards others. In the context of a relationship, it may also refer to traits of honesty, loyalty, romanticism, courtesy, and respect. **When used negatively**, a nice guy implies a male who is unassertive, does not express his true feelings and, in the context of dating (in which the term is often used), dishonestly uses acts of ostensible friendship and basic social etiquette with the unstated aim of progressing to a romantic or sexual relationship.

Na frase **"that's a real nice guy"**, dependendo do contexto, expressão facial e intonação, "nice guy" pode realmente ter significado positivo ou negativo. **Para o sentido pejorativo, em pt-BR, eu sugiro o substantivo "cafajeste".**
Enquanto em Portugal, principalmente em Coimbra, a palavra pode designar uma pessoa que não é estudante (**1**), no Brasil ela se refere a homens de má-índole e sem caráter. ([**Aulete**](http://www.aulete.com.br/cafajeste))  Dificilmente ouvimos o substantivo usado para alguém do sexo feminino e o contexto mais comum é alguém chegar para uma mulher e dizer "cuidado, esse cara é um cafajeste".   Isso certamente significa que o objetivo dele é  aproximar-se, fingindo ser um indivíduo íntegro, com o objetivo de conseguir alguma vantagem sexual ou financeira.  Também, ao final de um relacionamento, podemos ouvir de uma mulher: "descobri que ele era um cafajeste".

**1**. Esse significado realmente soa bem estranho aos nossos ouvidos brasileiros.

> - [**"cafajeste"**](https://cerebromasculino.com/o-que-e-um-cafajeste/)  Sempre suave, calmo, romântico, o cafajeste não tem escrúpulos, pensando apenas em atingir seu objetivo, independente do que precise ser feito. Parafraseando Maquiavel, para esse grupo de homens, “os fins justificam os meios” e se for necessário mentir, enganar, trair para ficar ou levar uma mulher pra cama, nada disso é mais importante que o seu objetivo.
>     Um cafajeste faz promessas de futuros encontros, namoros, casamento, viagens ou qualquer outra coisa. Envia mensagens SMS dizendo que está com saudades, te liga, marca encontros, fura, mas sempre vem com uma boa desculpa, agindo mais romântica e carinhosamente ainda.

Comment: Interessante sua interpretação da minha definição. De fato, *nice guys* são manipulativos e sem cáracter, embora sem ter consciência disso. Elaborei minha pergunta para deixar clara a conotação do termo.

Comment: @DetachedLaconian  Eu não interpretei a sua definição.  As definições existem nos dicionários, tanto a de significado positivo quanto a de negativo.  Editei minha resposta para torná-la mais clara.

Comment: É verdade: a definição não é minha, apenas a parafraseei. Não me toquei que o mais importante não era a definição, mas a conotação do termo *nice guy*: a ideia de que *nice guys finish last*, a oposição entre *nice guys* e *bad boys*, etc. Peço desculpas pela confusão e pela edição substancial da minha pergunta. Agradeço sua atenção.

Answer (score -2):

Levando em consideração o exemplo que você colocou na pergunta o "nice guy" seria um *amigo colorido* , aquele em que a mulher tem mais intimidade e também sente-se aberta a ter uma casinho ou um relacionamento mesmo que momentâneo.